# finding the possible variables

Tags: combinatorics

i need to find the number of possible variables in this equation which is not a problem but i was wondering if there is an actual combinatorics way to do this and not like i did , the way i did it was like making a small table

we need to find $<j,k,l>$ all $natural$ numbers (including 0) $2j+3k+5l=10$

[image: my way]

i think my answer is right but it does not seem to be an actual mathematical way to solve it

thanks for any kind of help !

Comment: Looks good.  To be systematic about it, fix $L$.  Clearly $L≤2$.  If $L=2$, there is only $(0,0,2)$.  If $L=1$ then you need to solve $2J+3K=5$ which only has one solution.  If $L=0$ then you need to solve $2J+3K=10$ which you can do my inspection (or fixing values of $K$).

Comment: As for if there is an "*actual mathematical method*"... arguably your method *is* an actual mathematical method.  If looking for a more *common* method, you could use generating functions.  For your example, looking at the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)(1+x^5+x^{10})$, but to be honest that is just brute force in disguise, letting a computer do the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the maximum values j, k and l can be. max(j)=5, max(k)=3, max(l)=2.
Then we can note, that 2j is always even and so is 10, so k+l must be even.
Then let's look at all the pairs of k and l, which suit the constraints above.
Obv. there's 1 solution with l=2 and k=0 and j=0.
With l=1, k is either 1 or 3. 1 works, 3 doesn't. There we have another solution.
With l=0, k is either 0 or 2. There we get 2 more solutions.